# Where is the number "0.963" in the paper "Why Isn't Everyone a Bayesian?" by Bradley Efron coming from?

Tags: probability, bayesian, median, frequentist

[This](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2683105) paper by Bradley Efron (also available [here](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Spring10/sta122/Handouts/EfronWhyEveryone.pdf)) concerning Bayesian vs. frequentist interpretation of probability contains an example I don't quite understand.

It's on page two in the right column in paragraph two. It goes like this:

> Consider 15 random numbers $x_{1}, \dots, x_{15}$ drawn from an
> unknown probability distribution $F$ on real numbers. To estimate the
> median of the distribution $\theta$, Frequentists can easily construct
> the confidence interval  $$ \theta \in [x_{(3)}, x_{(12)}], $$ which
> contains the median with a probability 0.963, no matter what $F$ is.
> $x_{(i)}$ denotes the $i$-th largest value of the 15 random numbers.

After talking with colleagues and thinking I am not possible to come up with the same answer. The best idea I have is this: A random number has, by construction, a probability of 0.5 of being larger than the median of it's probability distribution. Thus the probability that for a (of course fixed but unknown $\theta$) the interval of the third largest value to the 12 largest value does not contain the median is
$$
p(\theta \in [x_{(3)}, x_{(12)}]) = 1-\sum_{k=1, 2, 13, 14, 15}\binom{15}{k} 0.5^{15} \approx 0.9926
$$
which is obviously not 0.963.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's a typographical error: please read the interval as $(x_{3},x_{12})$ or $[x_{4},x_{11}].$

Comment: In addition, it should be 0.965. You draw 15 observations that can be either above or below the median (assuming a continuous distribution). $x_{(4)}$ will be above the median iff exactly 0, 1, 2 or 3 of the observations are below it. The [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) helps: the probability for that is (in R) `sum(dbinom(0:3,15,0.5))`. The same argument holds for the upper tail. Overall, your confidence interval has a coverage of `1-2*sum(dbinom(0:3,15,0.5))`, or 0.965.

Comment: I think I converge to understanding... @StephanKolassa Does the 2* in your code really work? The tails are asymmetric.

Comment: @Ludwig The tails are not asymmetric when the probability is 0.5

Comment: What Lukas Lohse said. It's the same argument, and the probabilities are 0.5 either way, whether we look at an observation being higher or lower than the median.